# What does <argument> mean put next to the template class name

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, metaprogramming

In the header file "std_function.h" there is this template class, I know what it does but I got curious about `<_Res(_ArgsTypes...)>`. I've never seen anywhere something like that

```
template<typename _Signature>
class function

template<typename _Res, typename... _ArgTypes>
    class function<_Res(_ArgTypes...)>
    : public _Maybe_unary_or_binary_function<_Res, _ArgTypes...>,
      private _Function_base {
           //...body of class
};
```

Can anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 0):

`_Res(_ArgTypes...)` is the type of a function taking `_ArgTypes...` as parameters and returning something of type `_Res`

Comment: Ok I understood that, but this was just an example, what do I do putting argument after the class name

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: an usual template class is declared like the following example `template<class T, class ...Args> class myClass;`, instead for function there are some argument that follow the class name like the following example `template<class T, class ...Args> class myClass<T(Args...)>;`, I hope to have made myself clear